# How to write HTML in Uk English?

Tags: html, lang

So my question is how to write html in British English, not American English as it is default. I know about the `lang` and `hreflang` tags and how you can use `en` but can you use a British version. I've tried to use `en-GB` but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: HTML is a mark up language.  It doesn't come in British English, or American or Japanese.  It's a language itself.  I think you need to further explain what you're after and provide an example.

Comment: I do not believe there is a code that differentiates, but here is the list of what's available: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: Would be ackward. Dutch HTML be like <hoofd> & <lichaam> instead of <head> & <body>.

Comment: Language tags are used to indicate the language of text or other items in HTML and XML documents, not the HTML itself. Such as if you have a cancel button with text that says "Abbrechen", anyone looking at the code will know it's German if  lang is set to the country code for Germany. But the HTML will still be English.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I'm just plain stupid. Didn't understand the function of lang tags.

Answer (score 1):

i typed en-gb and accepted
and you can check in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_country_codes.asp the codes accepted[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG8kE.png)

Comment: The `en-gb` was mentioned in the Question, the link was mentioned in the comments and both also mentioned in the accepted answer. Posting another answer with this is not very useful.